# Elementary question about quanta

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation

I've been trying to read about the origins of quantum physics, and I have not found a very satisfactory answer to this question.

The ultraviolet catastrophe resulted from, as I understand it, the experimental realization that high frequency/short wavelength radiation actually had less energy intensity than expected. Rayleigh-Jeans would have predicted the energy intensity to grow toward infinity as wavelength decreased. Right?

But the experiments showed differently, and you can find diagrams on the net that compare the observed black body radiation with the classical prediction. These diagrams show an positively sloped curve, increasing as wavelengths get longer, peaking, and the falling with a negative slope as wavelengths get larger.

So my question. What explains the shape of this curve? Why does high-frequency radiation have less blackbody radiation and then rise to a peak and then fall? I undersand why it would fall at longer wavelengths, but why does short wavelength/high frequency have a positive slope up to its peak?

I've read online that the quanta at high frequency are highly energetic (makes sense) and that therefore there are "fewer of them" and, since radiation is packetized, there is overall less energy intensity left of the peak. But I don't really understand this. Help?

Comment: maybe this link will help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html

Comment: That's a great site. But it still doesn't give me the intuitive explanation I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you have some intuitive *feel* for why in a a fixed volume and at a thermal equilibrium with its environment gas molecules have an average temperature-dependent velocity/kinetic energy with an appropriate distribution density that has a *peak*? if yes, then why not the EM waves in a cavity in a thermal equilibrium with the cavity walls that absorb and emit said waves?

Comment: Not really, to be honest.